# ENQUEUE Script directly rather then registering first

Tags: javascript, php, css

How does registering a stylesheet then enqueue-ing it differ from directly enqueue-ing it?

Here I registered then enqueued.

```
    function calling_script(){
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_uri(). `enter code here`'/css/bootstrap.min.css',array(),'1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
    wp_register_style('style', get_template_uri(). '/css/style.css',array(),'1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_style','calling_script');
```

Here I enqueued directly:

```
function calling_resources(){
    //Calling Styles
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri(),'','1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style('comment_style',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/comments.css','','1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style('404 style',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-404.css','','1.0.0');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','calling_resources');
```

Both work the same. But I saw many experts doing in these two different ways.

Comment: can you please add the actual code and not the images? it'll help  more other people with problems similar to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wp_register_style :-

This means, if you want to register your scripts, but not directly load them in your pages, you can register the files once, and then load them when you need them.

wp_enque_style :-
It helps you load the script

Comment: So, I should enqueue..ok Man